# How do I print the following objects of a list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
lst = ['Daniel', '2', 'daniel@outlook.com', 'Jay', '1212', 'jay@siber.com']
```

and as you can see it shows a number and a email, let´s say the number 2 and daniel@outlook.com are Daniel "attributes" only.

How can I build a function that will allow me from a `raw_input` to print those, for example:

```
n = str(raw_input("Enter the name on the list:"))
if n in lst:
   print(...) #(2 and daniel@outlook.com) 
else:
   print("Name is not on the List")
```

And it has to work like this for Jay also. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you all @zvone had the most completed answer and within the solution to my problem. Merry Xmas to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems best to change your data structure into a dictionary, so instead of:

```
lst = ['Daniel', '2', 'daniel@outlook.com', 'Jay', '1212', 'jay@siber.com']
```

you would have:

```
dct = {'Daniel': ('2', 'daniel@outlook.com'), 'Jay': ('1212', 'jay@siber.com')}
```

Then, you can do exactly what you wrote:

```
if name in dct:
    print dct[name]
```

**EDIT**

To create a dictionary:

```
names = lst[::3]
numbers = lst[1::3]
emails = lst[2::3]
dct = {name: (number, email)
       for name, number, email
       in zip(names, numbers, emails)}
```

Comment: Can you convert a list in a Dict? With a built-in function?

Comment: You have to read your list 3-by-3 items. The first item will be *name*, second *number*, third *email*. Then just do: `dct[name] = number, email`. To iterate 3-by-3, I would loop through indexes in `range(0, len(lst), 3)`.

Comment: Ah, even better... `names = lst[::3]`, `numbers = lst[1::3]`, `emails = lst[2::3]`. Then, `for name, number, email in zip(names, numbers, emails):...`

Comment: Can you rearrange your code so it will make the conversion from list to Dict and work how I want in order for me to implement it and better understanding what your saying. Thanks

Comment: @Phyti I added it to my answer

Comment: Thank you @zvone I will try to implement it and tell you if it works how I want

Comment: it works brilliantly thank you very much. Merry Xmas

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a dictionary instead of a list :

```
names = {'Daniel':['2', 'daniel@outlook.com'], 'Jay': ['1212', 'jay@siber.com']}
n=raw_input("Enter the name on the list:")   ## Your input statement 
print(names.get(n, "Name is not in the list"))
```

This will eliminate the need for the if check as well.

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> 
Enter the name on the list:Daniel
['2', 'daniel@outlook.com']

>>> 
Enter the name on the list:df
Name is not in the list
```

Comment: Also , no need to use str() on raw_input. Input returns string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a dictionary of lists, for example:

```
lst = {'Daniel': ('2', 'daniel@outlook.com'), 'Jay': ('1212', 'jay@siber.com')}
```

Then in your function use:

```
if n in lst:
    print(lst[n])
```

Comment: Nice, same timing too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by first turning your list into a dictionary keyed on the name:

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(*args)

lst = ['Daniel', '2', 'daniel@outlook.com', 'Jay', '1212', 'jay@siber.com']

dlst = dict([(name, (num, email)) for name, num, email in grouper(lst, 3)])
```

Then you can just look up the values you want in the dict as input comes in:

```
print(dlst.get(raw_input('Enter the name on the list: '),
               "Name is not in the list"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other were faster, but I'll post my answer anyway, as I included function that prints it in a pretty way

```
dict = {'Daniel': ['daniel@outlook.com', '2'], 'Jay': ['jay@siber.com', '1212']}

def func():
    name = raw_input("Enter the name on the list: ")
    if name in dict:
        print ', '.join(dict[name])
    else:
        print "Name was not found"
```

Result:

```
>>> func()
Enter the name on the list: Daniel
daniel@outlook.com, 2
>>> func()
Enter the name on the list: dsgd
Name was not found
```